# Uncaught Syntax Error: Identifier 'URL' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, identifier

This is my code even if I am changing the name from URL TO API_URL, still is the same error. By the way the code which I have written is only to learn about how API's works and learn about Twitter API.
In the backend, I am using a variable as const URL. That's I thought may be it is due to same name error in backend and the frontend. That's why I tried to change the name as I said earlier from URL TO API_URL but still it isn't working.

```
const URL = "http://localhost:3000/tweets";


const onEnter = (e) => {
    if(e.key == "Enter"){
        getTwitterData();
    }
}

/**
 * Retrive Twitter Data from API
 */
const getTwitterData = () => {
    
    const query = document.getElementById("user-search-input").value;
    if(!query) return;
    const encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    const fullurl =`${URL}?q=${encodedQuery}&count=10`;
    fetch(fullurl).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        buildTweets(data.statuses);
    })
}

/**
 * Save the next page data
 */
const saveNextPage = (metadata) => {
}

/**
 * Handle when a user clicks on a trend
 */
const selectTrend = (e) => {
}

/**
 * Set the visibility of next page based on if there is data on next page
 */
const nextPageButtonVisibility = (metadata) => {
}

/**
 * Build Tweets HTML based on Data from API
 */
const buildTweets = (tweets, nextPage) => {
    let twitterContent = "";
    tweets.map((tweet)=>{
        twitterContent += `
        <div class="tweet-container">
                        <div class="tweet-user-info">
                            <div class="tweet-user-profile">

                            </div>
                            <div class="tweet-user-name-container">
                                <div class="tweet-user-fullname">
                                    Abhishek Sagar
                                </div>
                                <div class="tweet-user-username">
                                    @abhisheksagar_
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tweet-images-container">
                            <div class="tweet-image">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tweet-text-container">
                            ${tweet.full_text}
                        </div>
                        <div class="tweet-date-container">
                            20 hours ago
                        </div>
                    </div>`
    })

    document.querySelector('.tweets-list').innerHTML = twitterContent;
    
}

/**
 * Build HTML for Tweets Images
 */
const buildImages = (mediaList) => {

}

/**
 * Build HTML for Tweets Video
 */
const buildVideo = (mediaList) => {

}
```

Comment: If the error stays the same when you change the name of the `const` then you're including the script twice.

Comment: Can you point where that script is twice, because I am not able to find that. Not even Error is giving the line where the code is having error. E.g. SyntaxError at line 35. So that I can improve it.

Comment: Forget to tell When I change this code from buildTweets(data.statuses); to console.log(data). It's working. Isn't it weird error.

Answer (score 0):

Because in file html you twice write script.src

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).